# Unable to deploy smart contract through ether.camp on Ethereum Consortorium Blockchain

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, ether-camp

I have created a private ethereum block chain on azure using Ethereum consortorium block chain template.

After the deployment is suceeded I got the following attributes of block chain

1. ETHEREUM-RPC-ENDPOINT
2. Private key
3. User

Now by using ether.camp I am trying to deploy a contract by clicking a button "Send Contracts to Net". I am able to see the available contracts, configured the **JSON RPC URL** and **Pkey** .

When clicking on send I an getting the following message

> Account 0x2ad984558bd5c7df51024363e5752d65b2d4677d has only 0 wei, but
>   need 7944040000000000 to create the contract(s).

The account being mentioned is not even my account.

Can any one help how to overcome this issue or any other ways to deploy a smart contract to the ethereum network.

Thanks in advance,
Mahesh Gupta

Comment: Did you get any clue on this? I am also struggling in deploying my contract on Azure Ethereum Consortorium Blockchain.

Comment: I am now deploying using geth console. I am not using ether camp.